# Is there a way to download dSYM via the AppstoreConnect API?

Tags: app-store-connect

When ipa files are built with bitcode, App Store Connect re-generate dSYM.

Is there any way to download the dSYM files via App Store Connect API?
( I know fastlane can download the dSYM files. )

Comment: Do you know what I have to do using fastlane when my user has 2FA enabled and I run it in my CI? The action `download_dsyms` seems to not support application specific passwords or FASTLANE_SESSION, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.6 [you can](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/buildbundle/attributes).

Each build will have a field called `dSYMUrl` located within the build bundles attributes.

For the [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/19508) inclined, support has also been added for this.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the dsyms changed? Or we have to keep track of that ourselves. I'm not famaliar with bitcode but I assume that AppStore could rebuild the app twice?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing can be done about it yet. Message in [forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118647) and [discussion](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/17485) in fastlane. Generally, "Fastlane is using the old iTunes Connect API to get dSYMs and stuff because the new API does not support it. This old API is obviously not compatible with the ASC API key."